# Why doesn't Julia's Gadfly and draw work inside of Emacs?

Tags: emacs, julia, ess

Why does "draw" not work when run inside ESS + emacs (but works fine using the interpreter conventionally "julia myfile.jl")?

```
using Gadfly
draw(SVG("output.svg", 6inch, 3inch), plot([sin, cos], 0, 25))

julia> ERROR: draw not defined
```

0.3.0-prerelease+1940

ess-20140120.43

Gadfly                        0.2.5

Emacs 24.3.1

Comment: It does work for me. Are you sure Gadfly is installed? Does using Gadfly show any errors?

Comment: I get a ton of ambiguous definition warnings when I "use" any package.

Comment: does Gadfly.draw work? have you tried whos(Gadfly) to see what exported symbols it has? That would tell you if you successfully loaded Gadfly at least and if the Gadfly version you loaded exports the draw function.

Comment: Seems to be working for me now. I have no idea what was wrong. I believe Gadfly was loading properly because "plot" was working.

Answer (score 0):

Working now. I don't know what I did differently.